# How do I locate the last occurrence of string in a string?

Tags: .net, vb.net

Is there a function which would search for the last occurrence of a certain substring and return the index of it?

For example, if I want to search for the last occurrence of the char '`\`' in a file path '`C:\Program Files\Microsoft`'.

Comment: If you intention is path manipulation, I suggest looking at the methods of the `System.IO.Path` class rather than doing it manually.

Comment: Are you trying to get the file name from a given path, if yes use the System.IO.Path.GetFileName(<FULL_PATH>)? That's lot better

Comment: Extra tip: Use System.IO.Path to manipulate strings containing file paths. E.g., `Path.GetFileName("c:\test\text.txt")`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[string.LastIndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.lastindexof.aspx)

Answer (score 9):

You look for

```
 "somesthing".LastIndexOf("char/string");
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use: [string.LastIndexOf(String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1wdsy8fy.aspx)